# How to stop scratching my eyes

Tags: personal-care, eyesight

I used to be having a eye problem and went to a eye doctor who helped me get drugs to use and new glasses. I was okay and kept improving even after I lost the glasses a year later. Its now 6 years later and still no much problem with my eyes though I use my laptop for a long time. I keep a good distance and angle when on my laptop.
However sometimes I feel like scratching the eyes or rather the area around them. It feels sweet and nice doing that since it is a relaxing feeling. I have heard that its dangerous to do that all the time so I usually wash my face and it relieves me. How can I avoid this habit of feeling like scratching my eyes

Answer (score 3):

- I would still suggest that you see a doctor for professional advice on the issue
- Bathe the area in warm or cold water - I sometimes get really itchy eyes so opt for putting them under running cold water to try and relieve some of the irritation. Experiment with both cold and warm water to see what works for you best
- Cover the area - If you are unable to stop the urge to scratch, then you can just employ a physical barrier to completely stop you from being able to scratch. Unless of course you just remove said barrier to get the itchy goodness but then you must really love to scratch
- Put pressure on it - Sometimes I just find the most simple thing is to put a deal of pressure on it either by sitting on (if possible) or laying on it. This is usually the most effective for me personally so it might work for you too.

Answer (score 2):

I recently received a diagnosis of [Keratoconus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keratoconus) after a visit to the opticians caused the automated machines to return a reading far from my actual prescription.

On visiting the consultant, he checked the inside of my eyelids and noticed a redness that indicated an allergic inflammation which causes my to regularly rub my eyes.  The mechanical action of my rubbing my eyes over a number of years is what he believes has led to the shape of my cornea to change.

He prescribed me some eyedrops which are intended to prevent the allergic reaction of the inside of my eyelids which in turn reduces my need to rub my eyes.  It's early days yet and I have an appointment in summer 2017 to assess how successful this has been but it may very well be that you are suffering from something similar.

Your vision is too important to mess about with so I'd be inclined to suggest you speak to an optician about this as a priority.  It could very well be nothing but it's worth getting checked out ASAP.

Comment: I will try to see an optician on the issue